# Django Rest How to property deserialize nested json json list and create multiple objects?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a json like this:

```
{
    "items_data":[
        {
            "item_name": "Foo",
            "item_price": 1000
        },
        {
            "item_name": "Bar",
            "item_price": 99
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to extract a list of products from it, and create several objects. How to do it correctly?
I'm confused about having a key, I don't have a model associated with it.
My Item model:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My serializer, very basic:

```
class ItemCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('item_name', 'item_price')
```

I tried several options.
First, I tried to do it through views. Like this:

```
class ItemsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemCreateSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data['items_data'], many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But if the input is incorrect, I won't get a clear error message.

Also I tried to create a nested serializer like this:

```
    class ItemDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        items_data = ItemCreateSerializer(many=True)

        class Meta:
            fields = ('items_data',)

        def create(self, validated_data):
            items = validated_data.pop('items_data')
            for item_data in items:
                Item.objects.create(**items_data)
```

Now my view:

```
class ItemsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemDataSerializer
```

So, if а input json is wrong, I get an informative error in the response.
But I can't figure out how to write a create() method.
I am getting error:
"`create ()` did not return an object instance"
But I don't have such an object that I can return, I don't have such a model.

Or should I do it through methods to_internal_value?

**UPD:**

Thanks @vj-magar
So I did it like this:

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        items = validated_data.pop('items_data')
        created_items = (Item.objects.create(**item_data) for item_data in items)
        return {'items_data': created_items}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try return {} from the create method

```
def create(self, validated_data):
            items = validated_data.pop('items_data')
            for item_data in items:
                Item.objects.create(**items_data)
            return {}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but I get the error:
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `items_data` on serializer `ItemDataSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'items_data'."

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that the view is trying to serialize back the received data in order to return it in the response.
So I did it like this:

`created_items = (Item.objects.create(**item_data) for item_data in items)'` `return {'items_data': created_items}`


It works as expected, thanks!